# To what percentage of the speed of light you need to accelerate to get artificial gravity at 1g?

Tags: gravity, physics, interstellar-travel, relativistic-rocket

Let's say you have a very powerful hypothetical fusion or matter/antimatter drive on a spaceship and you want to travel to a star nearby. Can you get 1g artificial gravity by accelerating? Or close to 1g? The starship will have to turn halfway to decelerate. Anyway, will accelerating/decelerating at relativistic speeds give artificial gravity inside for the whole trip?

Comment: So, you'll need to accelerate continuously at 8.91m/s2 to get 1g? But no engine is powerful enough to achieve this in a near future. I wonder what power/thrust you'll need for example to get 5m/s2 a large mass like a starship (1.000 metric tons)?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The speed of the craft is not a factor in the acceleration felt by the passengers.

If the craft accelerates at 1 g, 1 g is what the passengers will feel, from the moment that the acceleration starts.

There is no current spacecraft engine technology that can produce anywhere near that level of acceleration for long periods of time.